# Adding a rank using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have some php code for pulling results from my database:

```
<?php  $res=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(step_count.steps) as total, 
leagues.league_id, leagues.league_name
    FROM step_count
    INNER JOIN logins on
      step_count.email=logins.email
    INNER JOIN leagues ON
      leagues.email=logins.email
    GROUP BY leagues.league_id, leagues.league_name
    ORDER BY `total` DESC LIMIT 10");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
      ?>

      <?php echo $row['league_name']; ?>
      <?php echo $row['total']; ?>
```

And I get the results as wanted which are

```
Test      | 6200 
TestTwo   | 5600 
TestThree | 3400
```

And I was wondering if there was a way to create rankings for these results so it looks like this without having to manually add the ranks myself

```
#1 Test      | 6200 
#2 TestTwo   | 5600 
#3 TestThree | 3400
```

Comment: You mean sorting by total

Comment: It's already sorting by the total, I would just like it to adding a ranking score next to it

Comment: on what parameter do you want to rank?  if it's an existing you can add an ORDER statement, or if you want some sort of display order you could add an display order column...

Comment: Where is ranking score?

Comment: Would you like to share your schema?

Comment: Where is your `ranking score` table

Comment: I don't have a table for the ranking score, I just simply want them to be listed as #1 if they have the highest score and so forth

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure mysql*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question you want to show number of column try this code

```
<?php  
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(step_count.steps) as total, 
    leagues.league_id, leagues.league_name
        FROM step_count
        INNER JOIN logins on
          step_count.email=logins.email
        INNER JOIN leagues ON
          leagues.email=logins.email
        GROUP BY leagues.league_id, leagues.league_name
        ORDER BY `total` DESC LIMIT 10 ");
        $rank = 1;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
    ?>
    <?php echo '#'.$rank++; ?>
    <?php echo $row['league_name']; ?>
    <?php echo $row['total']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```